# Haar Cascade Problem with detectMultiScale

Tags: python

So I ran the face cascade classifier:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

and when I used the code

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
```

I got the error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp:1658: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'detectMultiScale'

I'm not sure if it's because I installed OpenCV via pip? But since I installed via pip, there isn't really a folder I can go into to find the files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml is not found. Probably files does not exist in the current working directory.